# Passing data with circular references to a javascript web worker on Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web-worker

I am trying to delegate the html rendering of a tree to a web worker. The tree is composed of nodes, each nodes has references to the next, previous and parent nodes.

The data that represents the tree is an array, containing all the root nodes. This array is post to the web worker as is, since the serializer of the web worker is supposed to support circular references.

When there's few nodes, everything goes well.

Using Chrome browser, when the number of nodes reaches a limit, the web worker do not receive anything ; its message's data is simply null. No error appears in the console.

With Firefox, IE and Edge, everything is OK. But I need Chrome to work to.

I tried to simplify my code and make a case test (see the jsFiddle below), and it appears that the problem comes from the circular reference to the next node.
In this case test, with 100 elements everything goes well, with 1000 it doesn't work.

Is there any solution to this problem ?
Is the only solution to change my code to remove circular references ?

HTML:

```
<p><button id='btn_100'>Test 100</button><button id='btn_1000'>Test 1000</button></p>
```

Javascript:

```
var workerCode = "self.onmessage = function(e) { self.postMessage(e.data ? 'ok ' + e.data.length : 'ko : null data'); };",
    blob = new Blob([workerCode], {type: 'text/javascript'}),
    blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob),
    worker = new Worker(blobUrl);

var btn_100 = document.getElementById('btn_100'),
    btn_1000 = document.getElementById('btn_1000');

worker.onmessage = function(e) {
     var log = document.createElement('p');
     log.innerHTML = 'Response: <pre>' + e.data + '</pre>';
     document.body.appendChild(log);
 };

btn_100.onclick = function() { send(worker, 100); };
btn_1000.onclick = function() { send(worker, 1000); };

function send(w, n) {
    var a = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      a.push({});
      if (i > 0) a[i - 1].next = a[i];
    }
    w.postMessage(a);
}
```

Link to jsFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/jvr4a50r/

Comment: Interesting... On mine (65 on osx) I get a `null` when creating `[1336 - 3473]` objects. If I create more, then it throws a *Maximum Call stack*. This really smells like a Chrome bug, so the best is probably to let them know about it. For a temporary workaround, yes... removing circular references might indeed be the only solution...

Comment: Oh! It's not even because of cyclic objects... It's just about how deep your object is: https://jsfiddle.net/o96b3quk/. And even weirder, Window's `postMessage` does accept such deep object...

Comment: @Kaiido many thanks for the time you spent on this case. As suggested, I'll try to take time to report something to Google. For now, I will remove all circular references :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google has recognized this issue to be a bug:
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=825466

So far, to ensure having no problems, the only solution is to remove circular references in objects.

In this case I followed these steps:

- give a unique id to each node
- flatten the tree by putting all nodes in a "hasmap", the key is the unique id
- in nodes, replace all references to other nodes by the unique id
- and of course change all the code that used references to access objects indirectly through the hashmap

Answer (score 0):

Actuallty,shallow copy happen in next property of object with in array. So for removing circular references, you have to do deep copy in next property. 
You can remove circular references by updateing the send function in following way.

```
    var a = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      a.push({});
      if (i > 0) 
a[i - 1].next = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(a[i]));
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But if you serialize `next` attribute, the link with the real next element is completly lost : unserialization will create another element, not retrieve the real one. That apart, the real case is much more complex and I'm afraid the JSON serializer won't help at all...